# Basis vectors derivation from the position vector in general curvilinear coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vectors, coordinate-systems

In general coordinates, the basis vectors are defined as the derivatives of teh posituon vector:
$$\vec e_i = \frac { {\partial \vec R}} {\partial x^i}$$

Nonetheless, the position vector is given by:

$$\vec R= \sum_i x^i \vec e_i$$

and when we do the derivative we have:

$$\frac{\partial \vec R}{\partial x^n} = \sum_i(\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^n} \vec e_i + x^i \frac{\partial \vec e_i}{\partial x^n}) = \vec e_n + \sum_ix^i\frac{\partial \vec e_i}{\partial x^n} $$

Since the term $\sum_ix^i\frac{\partial \vec e_i}{\partial x^n}$ is not null in general, then the question is: where am I messing up?

Comment: $\vec{e}_i$ is being used to denote two different things here; the standard, euclidean basis vectors (which are constant) and the basis vectors associated with the curvilinear coordinates $R$. If might be a good to distinguish these two.

Comment: I would recommend to write

$$
\vec{R} = \sum_i x^i \vec{\epsilon}_i
$$

just so the difference between the Euclidean basis $\epsilon_i$ and the curvilinear vectors $e_i$ is more clear

Comment: Your equation for $\vec R$ as a linear combination of $\vec e_i$ is just wrong in general. Have you tried something like polar coordinates in the plane?

Comment: you deserve congrats for the right usage of  the indexing technique as $x^i$ for coordinates functions and $\vec e_i$ for basis vectors

Comment: OK, I think to have understood my error. The formula I used to express the position vector is valid just in Cartesian coordinates, not in general coordinates. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be considering $\vec R=\sum_i R^i\vec e_i$ (instead of $R=\sum_i x^i\vec e_i$) where
each $R^i$ are functions of the euclidean coordinates $x^j$. It is necessary that
the Jacobian matrix $J\vec R=\left[\frac{\partial R^i}{\partial x^j}\right]$ has determinant different from zero in the domain of definition of $R$.

A new basis for the space in these coordinates are
$$\vec \partial_k=\sum_s\frac{\partial R^s}{\partial x^k}\vec e_s,$$
which give you, may be, a non-orthogonal neither non-orthonormal frame of the space.

Comment: also, it is of common use to symbolize $\vec e_i$ for the canonical basis of the space which is  orthonormal

Comment: As said in the above comments, the issue is simply that the formula $\ vec R = \sum_i x^i \vec e_i$ is not valid in general coordinates but just in cartesian coordinates

Comment: yes, that is why you need to use $\vec R=\sum_s R^s\vec e_s$ where we have the dependence $R^s=R^s(x^1,...,x^n)$